# Why does watchman gives timeout error when using it with react-relay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay, watchman, react-relay

I'm using WSL Ubuntu to run a react-relay project, but after installing watchman using brew and trying to run the app in watch mode, watchman gives me the following error(I have run the project using `yarn start`):

```
Watchman error: The watchman server reported an error: "watchman::QueryExecError: query failed: synchronization failed: syncToNow: timed out waiting for cookie file to be observed by watcher within 60000 milliseconds: Connection timed out", while executing command: QueryRequest(
    "query",
    "/mnt/d/Work/Personal/react-relay-tutorial",
    QueryRequestCommon {
        glob: None,
        glob_noescape: false,
        glob_includedotfiles: false,
        path: Some(
        ...
```

I've been trying reinstalling watchman without brew, with brew, the same error I get, nothing on the internet helped...

My package.json file:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn run relay && react-scripts start",
    "build": "yarn run relay && react-scripts build",
    "relay": "yarn run relay-compiler --watch $@",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "relay": {
    "src": "./src/",
    "schema": "./src/schema.graphql"
  },
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^13.1.1",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0",
    "relay-compiler": "^13.1.1"
  }
...
```

relay.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  // Configuration options accepted by the `relay-compiler` command-line tool and `babel-plugin-relay`.
  src: './src',
  schema: './src/schema.graphql',
  exclude: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/__mocks__/**', '**/__generated__/**'],
};
```

.babel.rc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "relay"
  ]
}
```

Project structure:
[image]

PS: when running the project without any watchman it works just fine